# How can I Automate web application which is following two factor authentication?

Tags: selenium, automated-tests, single-sign-on, two-factor-authentication

I have to automate my web application login process. Steps have to follow manually are

-- login page opens --> enter credentials and click on login button
-- Now One mail will be sent to my personal outlook mail
-- I have to open that mail and click on one hyperlink text to open new window of application.

Please help me to how can I achieve this process by automation?

Answer (score 1):

You can connect to outlook backend using your email and password

If you working in java, probably below link will help you getting started.
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/javamail_api/javamail_api_checking_emails.htm

Once you are connected, read the new mail say with certain subject and extract that mail content into the string.

Then extract hyperlink  " " from that string and again you can use webdriver get to open that hyperlink in a separate window

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how much control you have over the *application under test*. If you can disable 2FA for test applications

> then I would recommend do that (mark the 2fa login scenario for manual tests)

If you can use mailtrap or any other utility like that you can then

> automate the step using mailtrap's APIs (or whatever tool you go with)

Another option can be

> use microsoft's API to validate the email that is delivered to your outlook account.